# Running Big Queries on Athena using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, aws-step-functions

As we know that Lambda timeouts after 15 minutes of execution. I am looking for a way to execute an Athena query which is on a really huge dataset. Invoking the query from Lambda will introduce the problem of Lambda timing out before the query is processed. My ultimate goal is to invoke the query and to know when the query is complete so I could process the results. Could a state machine be used to query Athena? or does Lambda function by only invoking the athena and not waiting for results, I'll query the athena for results after the duration in which I expect the query to run? Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Athena, you initiate a query and you get a unique Athena query execution ID back as a result. Athena executes the query asynchronously. Athena ultimately stores the results of the query in S3. You can later retrieve those results by making a 2nd API call passing in the original query execution ID.

See [Working with Query Results, Output Files, and Query History](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html).

Comment: so just invoke the athena query and let my lambda timeout after invocation, inspect the result after some hours should work

Comment: No. Your Lambda doesn’t timeout. Invoke the Athena query, persist the query ID as needed or simply return it as part of the response from the Lambda, and then exit the Lambda. It’s work is done.

Comment: ok so the athena query would be running in background? my assumption was that the lambda execution would be paused till the query runs, like a single threaded operation.

Comment: Yes. If you look at the APIs you’ll see that you ‘start’ a query execution.

Comment: The call using start_qeury_execution is asynchronous - not blocking. The query will continue in the "background" and the Lambda that initiated the query can exit immediately.

Comment: I want to actually, rename the S3 file to some specific name. I need to wait for the query execution to complete and then rename the S3 file. How can I achieve waiting for the execution to complete?

Comment: @shashwat how you wait is really up to you. Call the Athena API to get the status of the query periodically to determine if it’s complete. Or investigate if you can trigger a Lambda when the Athena query results are dropped into S3, so you don’t have to actually wait but can potentially trigger an action when complete.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the suggestion! I just hoped if there is any built-in support to wait for the execution. Since my queries are pretty lightweight and do need to run often. I implemented the wait inside lambda itself by keep checking the result of `GetQueryExecutionCommand` (js) with some delay.